# Error: global.nativeTraceBeginSection is not a function

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I didnt change anything but suddenly I got this error in my xproject and the app got stuck and thing the when I do simulator through my Xcode is working but not with physical device.
  the full log is here:

```
        'Failed to print error: ', 'global.nativeTraceBeginSection is not a function. (In \'global.nativeTraceBeginSection(TRACE_TAG_REACT_APPS, profileName, args)\', \'global.nativeTraceBeginSection\' is undefined)'
       WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
   E0910 19:37:09.077337 1871998976 JSCHelpers.cpp:137] Got JS Exception: Exception calling object as function: global.nativeTraceEndSection is not a function. (In 'global.nativeTraceEndSection(TRACE_TAG_REACT_APPS)', 'global.nativeTraceEndSection' is undefined) (<unknown file>:2303)
  E0910 19:37:09.077525 1871998976 JSCHelpers.cpp:143] Got JS Stack: endEvent@http://192.168.1.27.xip.io:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2303:35
  __callFunction@http://192.168.1.27.xip.io:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2098:24
  http://192.168.1.27.xip.io:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:1927:29
__guard@http://192.168.1.27.xip.io:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2068:11
 callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@http://192.168.1.27.xip.io:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:1926:19
 callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]
2018-09-10 19:37:09.079 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Error calling Systrace.setEnabled

 Unhandled JS Exception: Exception calling object as function: global.nativeTraceEndSection is not a function. (In 'global.nativeTraceEndSection(TRACE_TAG_REACT_APPS)', 'global.nativeTraceEndSection' is undefined) (<unknown file>:2303)
2018-09-10 19:37:09.082 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] global.nativeTraceBeginSection is not a function. (In 'global.nativeTraceBeginSection(TRACE_TAG_REACT_APPS, profileName, args)', 'global.nativeTraceBeginSection' is undefined)
2018-09-10 19:37:09.083 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] 'Failed to print error: ', 'Can\'t find variable: regeneratorRuntime'
E0910 19:37:09.086755 1871998976 JSCHelpers.cpp:137] Got JS Exception: Exception calling object as function: global.nativeTraceBeginSection is not a function. (In 'global.nativeTraceBeginSection(TRACE_TAG_REACT_APPS, profileName, args)', 'global.nativeTraceBeginSection' is undefined) (<unknown file>:2298)
E0910 19:37:09.086828 1871998976 JSCHelpers.cpp:143] Got JS Stack: beginEvent@http://192.168.1.27.xip.io:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2298:37
__invokeCallback@http://192.168.1.27.xip.io:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2125:28
http://192.168.1.27.xip.io:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:1950:32
__guard@http://192.168.1.27.xip.io:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2068:11
invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue@http://192.168.1.27.xip.io:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:1949:19
invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]
(lldb)
```

I have been trying to find solution, didn't succeed with any of them.
this error shows on my Xcode logged and not on my screen of the phone

Thank you so much for the help!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known, unresolved React Native issue. There are a few workarounds in the GitHub issue, including:

- Delete, and then reinstall the app from Xcode or `react-native run-ios`
- Revert to the old bridge ([instructions](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15003#issuecomment-323715121))

See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15003 for more details.

Comment: hi , what do you mean in Delete, and then reinstall the app from Xcode? how can I do it?

Comment: Just delete the app from the simulator or device… then rebuild…

Comment: This one works for me! But I think it’s only temporary solution, it might comes back. Btw do you know why suddenly it happens? Before that I had never this problem but suddenly it started

Comment: I’m not sure what causes it, but from the code it may relate to a bug in the C++ bridge. Please mark the answer as correct if it resolved your issue so that others know you aren’t still seeking help.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue because I unintentionally enabled **Start Systrace** and since it is a known react native issue... I was getting the error.

What worked for me was just disabling **Start Systrace** and restarting the project. How I do that?

<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

[image: img]

Press **Disable Start Systrace**, that's it!

Comment: Thanks that's work for me, As I open debug tool in MAC OS emulator: Press Control + Command + Z, click Disable start Systrace, and I run againg: npx react-native run-ios